# Update the "non-reproducible" close reason to cover a problem in unposted code

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, scope

More than once I've come across questions that are caused by code unrelated to the posted code.

Typically they go along the lines of "Here's my simplified code. I expected it to do X, but Y is occuring instead. Why is this, and how can I fix it?", and end with a comment of "I figured it out, my problem was some other code that is not related or displayed here".

When voting to close, I have two possible options :

- Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

I don't like picking the first one because of its emphasis that the question was closed due to being unclear or of poor quality. Often the user *has* supplied the desired behavior, the specific problem or error, and a trimmed down version of their code to demonstrate what they think to be the problem, and the question quality is fine despite the flaw in the OP's logic. To me, this doesn't seem very helpful to the user (who actually is trying to follow the rules) or to future readers.

The second close reason seems more appliable, with its emphasis on the cause being unrelated to the posted code, such as a typo or something that can't be reproduced. It would make sense that this close reason would also be used in cases where the problem is caused by unrelated code, or OP overlooking something stupid (I've done this many times!), despite that specific wording not existing here.

Can we change that second close reason to add wording for that additional reason:

- This question was caused by either **a problem that can no longer be reproduced**, **a simple typographical error**, or **code unrelated to the question posted**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

It seems much more appliable in cases like this for why a question is getting closed.

Comment: One big difference between these two close reasons: the first feels like a prospective close reason ('this won't be a good/useful question as it stands') while the second feels like a retrospective reason ('Problem is fixed and it's not something we're going to bother posting since it was a boneheaded move').  You like the latter because it seems right - it's retrospective.  But technically the reason the question needs closing is that it isn't answerable as it stands - it doesn't include the code to repro the problem- not that it's caused by a bug, unless it was ALSO, in which case both work.

Comment: @Joe: The retrospective nature of typo has always kind of bugged me, since pretty much all other close reasons can be applied before the question is answered, but typo can only be applied if you *have an answer ready* (and that answer is "it was a typo"). Perhaps I should open a discussion on how to improve that sometime.

Answer (score 71):

Technically the first of the two close reasons would apply given the following snippet:

> the shortest **code** necessary **to reproduce** it

(emphasis mine.)

The question contains code, but the code provided doesn't reproduce the problem described.  If the OP hadn't yet realized that his code doesn't reproduce the problem, I would likely comment as well as VTC, but in your case the author already knows that his question doesn't contain code that is able to reproduce the problem.

It's also worth noting that this whole close reason is basically just a subset of "unclear", so "unclear" wouldn't really be wrong either, although it would perhaps be less informative.

Now, this first close reason could potentially be edited to greater emphasize that both a problem statement and reproducible example are needed, possibly by adding a reference to the latter in the following sentence, such as:

> Questions without a clear problem statement **and a reproducible example** are not useful to other readers.

(Emphasis denotes added text, not the formatting of the result.)

Comment: You beat me to it. But yes, the first close reason appears to be the better match, although it could (perhaps) be clarified slightly.

Comment: Yes, that's why I included that close reason in my question. It does technically contain the reason, but it it doesn't seem very useful to the OP or future readers at pointing out exactly why the question was closed because its emphesis is on the question not being clear or containing enough information to answer, which is often not the case. The second close reason seems more on target since it focuses on a post being closed due to the problem not being reproducable or a typographical error on the user part, so I was thinking it would make more sense to include "unrelated code" here too.

Comment: @Rachel The OP not being able to reproduce their own problem is radically different than other readers not being able to reproduce the OP's problem.  The former is an issue with the type of problem not being one that SO can really address, the latter is a problem with the question's representation of the problem and not the problem itself.  The use of the term "reproducible" in the latter is really a red herring here; it's pretty far off from what's going on in your example.

Comment: Yeah, my main dislike for that close reason is the emphesis on being an unclear or poorly worded question, which is sometimes not the case. I like the second close reason because its emphesis is on the cause being a stupid or unrelated mistake, which is how I view these kinds of questions.

Comment: @Rachel The close reason is there for questions that are missing key information in order for them to be answerable, specifically missing either a description of the problem, or the means to reproduce it.  This is exactly the type of question that that close reason exists to apply to.  The other close reason both doesn't apply to these types of questions, and wasn't ever intended to.

Comment: @Rachel, there's a big difference between the first ("needs improvement of a specific type") and the second ("no longer useful").

Comment: Yeah, the first one sounds perfect to me. It says "the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**", so if the code necessary to reproduce the problem isn't in the question, then that close reason applies.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think closure reflects negatively on the asker. If the question is *bad*, it will get down-voted. Closure means the question is not useful or appropriate as it currently stands. No one coming later will be able to get anything out of the question if the code that actually matters is not included. Thus I would choose the first of the two close reasons.

I *do*, however, have a different quibble with the wording of the second: sometimes a problem goes beyond "a simple typographical error", but the question won't be any more useful to future visitors than one caused by such a thing. In particular, this is often the case with type errors in languages with powerful type systems. There may be a deep problem with the code causing the type error, and maybe even subtle issues at play, but the question (Why do I get a type error when trying to do X?) will never, ever be found by someone who encounters the same problem, because there will be practically no relationship between the texts of the questions, and they may trigger significantly different errors.

Comment: "and they may trigger significantly different errors [for that reader]." in that case, an answer to that question would not help that reader anyway. However, another reader encountering the same error and looking for the error message could find the question, and find the answer useful. An error like `type mismatch;  found   : List[List[...]]  required: List[...]` could have an answer like "use `flatMap` instead of `map`"

Comment: (maybe you're talking about a very specific example where that's not the case, but I don't think the generalization applies. Obviously I'm not defending people who paste compiler output without thinking)

Comment: @SillyFreak, I'm speaking from my experience seeing GHC messages posted here. The types are very often user-defined, the specific details of where inference went wrong can make the same underlying issue lead to different error messages, etc., etc.